# Java Self Reference with Inhertiance

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, field, self-reference

I understand why this code below doesn't work. That's because convolusion will call **Base**, not **Derived**. This code is soooo simple, and have self-referencing. I extended 'self-referencing class' and I stucked with that problem.

```
class Base
{
    public    int  important_data;
    protected Base child;

    public int sum()
    {
        if(child != null)
        {
            return important_data + child.sum();
        }
        else
        {
            return important_data;
        }
    }
}

class Derived extends Base
{
    public int more_important;

    public int convolusion()
    {
        if(child != null)
        {
            return more_important*important_data + child.convolusion();
        }
        else
        {
            return more_important*important_data;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, is there any available method to do that?

Comment: How can you be sure that the child will be of Derived type when calling convolusion ?

Comment: `child` don't know about `convolusion()` method.

Comment: @Braj Well actually I'm working Tree with self referencing class. I want to do some iteration using kind of DFS- And I want to extend original Tree class. And also, there is sentinel with null, so when reached no child it will stop.

Comment: create an empty or abstract method `public int convolusion()` in `Base` class and override in `Derived` class.

Comment: @X.L.Ant That's the point. I can't sure that is 'Derived'. So I wonder another way. I can't override field of course.

Comment: @Braj Well, that is very straight forward but it seems to spoil capsulize

Comment: @user3811223 You can't be sure, but you can check that at runtime, and process accordingly.

Comment: how it will spoil capsulize? please explain a bit more.

Comment: @Braj You can't feel capsulize in this fool example, but in pratical situation, I heard that inheritance is a way to "Extend" the base class. Base can be extended with any other classes that doesn't contain convolusion(), I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or, you can use a generic base class:

```
class Base<T extends Base> {
    private T child;
    private int importantData;

    Base(T child) {
        this.child = child;
    }

    Base() {
        this(null);
    }

    public int sum() {
        if (child != null && child != this) {
            return importantData + child.sum();
        } else {
            return importantData;
        }
    }

    protected T child() {
        return child;
    }

    protected int importantData() {
        return importantData;
    }
}

class Derived extends Base<Derived> {
    private int moreImportant;

    public int convolusion() {
        if (child() != null && child() != this) {
            return moreImportant * importantData() + child().convolusion();
        } else {
            return moreImportant * importantData();
        }
    }
}
```

This way you get type safe handling, no casting is needed.

Comment: That really makes sense with the safety(Especially != this)! But, because I don't know the generic class, I should study more about it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show where you initialize the `child` member. In order to call `child.convolusion()`, you have to make sure that `child` is of type `Derived`, and cast it to `Derived`.

```
public int convolusion()
{
    if(child != null && child instanceof Derived)
    {
        Derived d = (Derived) child;
        return more_important*important_data + d.convolusion();
    }
    else
    {
        return more_important*important_data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure the type of the child, trying something like:

```
if(child != null && child instanceof Derived)
{
    return more_important * important_data + ((Derived)child).convolusion();
}
```